# How to remove duplicates based on multiple dynamic columns

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk

using bash(awk), how do I remove duplicates  from a pipe delimited file based on multiple columns but columns need to be passed as input arguments.
I have below data in the file

```
Insert|val1|val2|val3|val4 
Insert|val1a|val2|val3a|val4
```

I want to remove duplicates based on input argument. Sometimes I want rows dropped using position 1 and position 3 and sometimes using position2 and position3.
I am using this

```
 awk -F, '!seen[$1,$3 ]++ '
```

but don't know how to parameterize $1,$2

Comment: ITYM `-F'|'`, not `-F,`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you're trying to do:

```
$ awk -v c='1 3' -F'|' 'BEGIN{split(c,k," ")} {key=""; for (i in k) key=key FS $(k[i])} !seen[key]++' file
Insert|val1|val2|val3|val4
```

Comment: Yes, this works. I just need figure out how make '1 3' as argument for the script. Thanks

Comment: `script 1 3` then inside `awk -v c="$*" '...' file`.

Comment: I am facing another issue.plz check this <https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/698261/how-to-remove-duplicates-from-pipe-delimited-file-using-awk-with-pipe-in-values>.